# VTD-XML Parsing Performance (speed critical factor). Requesting Feedback/Comments

Tags: java, xml, performance, vtd-xml

I am about to use VTD-XML (found at http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) but I am interested in getting real-case usage feedback, by any one that has used the library and has any comments.

At the URL (http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) there are benchmarks but if someone has used VTD-XML and has comments FOR it I would like to hear them. Speed is a critical factor in the application and comments after real-case usage, by developers, is what i am looking for.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VTD-XML performance has been measured by a number of sources, below are some of them

1. This report (https://code.ai.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/trac/xcf/wiki/Evaluation) has numbers that measures the parsing/xpath performance comparing to XOM, binary XML, SAX and DOM
2. Also xmlbench (search it on the web as a keyword) will lead you the open source project dedicated to XML parsing performance site
3. VTD-XML web site also has a number of benchmark reports (there will be updates soon).

   4. here is a paper by some Portugal researchers  published in 2013. [http://sdiwc.net/digital-library/web-admin/upload-pdf/0](http://sdiwc.net/digital-library/web-admin/upload-pdf/00000466.pdf)0000466.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for comments from developers that have used it. Tend to be a little cautious with benchmark reports from the sites that release the libraries.

Comment: You have every right to be cautious ... I think they release more than just the benchmark report, but the test code and XML files as well so you can do it yourself and verify the results...

Comment: Here is one more link from someone who has tried it http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2715769/Excellent-Parser.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I use VTD-XML for faster XPaths. Previously, my application was using DOM to apply XPaths on a document which took about 20 minutes on a 17MB document. I thought about switching to SAX, but SAX does not support XPaths, is quite "user-unfriendly" and would have required a lot of code restructuring. So I migrated quite painlessly to VTD-XML and my xml processing now takes about 20 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

I found VTD-XML was indeed faster for parsing and XPAth however I did find it used a lot more memory for XPath than DOM. In addition, the Java version 2.10 just did not work with attributes and XPath so it was a no go.

Comment: Did have some memory issues when using Strings so a switch to char[] and stringBuffer/Builder was necessary.

Comment: That would not even be a big issue for me (the memory I measured was from what vtd-xml returned to me so nothing I could do about it). The attributes issue is bigger it does not work in 2.10 or 2.0 for Java and I'm wondering if it ever worked.

Comment: I found it highly unlikely that vtd-xml consumes more memory than dom. It is virtually impossible. The attribute issue is a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: That was some time ago (2010) that I tested it by snapshotting memory before and after instantiating required VTD xml classes for XPATH. You are welcome to benchmark it again. But note this was for XPath. This is far from impossible but a well known space-time tradeoff effect (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff)